# Python regex help

Tags: python, regex

```
a = Account(unit = 2, path='/real/os/win/today/axl.xls', realname = 'st')
```

What I want is escape the ' to html entities, which is `&#39;`

remember, the string after path can be anything, I need a generic way to do this.

The output of this string is

```
Account(unit = 2, path=&#39;/real/os/win/today/axl.xls&#39;, realname = 'st')
```

Comment: Do you want to do this _in_ python, meaning the sample you provided is actual code, or _with_ python, meaning the code you provided will be a string manipulated using python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
re.sub(r"path=\'([^\']*)\'", "path=&#39;\1&#39;", str)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert '/real/os/win/today/axl.xls' to `&#39;/real/os/win/today/axl.xls&#39;` you can use `"'/real/os/win/today/axl.xls'".replace("'", '&#39;')` instead of using regex.

Answer (score 0):

What you have are non-HTML entities. If I remember it right, there are 3 such types of `&...` entities, e.x.- `&#160; &#xa0; &nbsp;` all mean `U+00A0 NO-BREAK SPACE`.

`&#160;` - (the type you have) is a "numeric character reference" (decimal).

`&#xa0;` - is a "numeric character reference" (hexadecimal).

`&nbsp;` -  is an entity.

You could check out Fredrick Luth's **[Unescape HTML script](http://effbot.org/zone/re-sub.htm#unescape-html)** (for python2.x) & more about [**HTML entities here**](http://htmlhelp.com/reference/html40/entities/)

Answer (score 0):

if i understood the question correctly:

```
>>> a = "Account(unit = 2, path='/real/os/win/today/axl.xls', realname = 'st')"
>>> re.sub("(?<=path=').*", lambda x: '&#39'+x.group(0), a)
"Account(unit = 2, path='&#39/real/os/win/today/axl.xls', realname = 'st')"
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer `BeautifulSoup` for all this stuff. Check out http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html#Entity%20Conversion for more.